# View local variables on CentOS

Tags: shell, environment-variables, variable

How can I view local variables? If I create a local variable e.g. `VR1=rhe17` I'm not able to see it when running `printenv` unless I make it an environment variable using `export VR1`.

Comment: type `env` for getting the local variable. `echo $VR1` will give you the output.

Answer (score 1):

To see variables which are local to the current shell, you need to use the shell builtin, `set`: without any arguments it will output all the variables with their values.

`env` and `printenv` are external commands (typically in `/usr/bin`), so they will only display exported variables.

Comment: Thank you. How would i delete a local variable?

Comment: `unset` deletes the given local variable.

Comment: Ok. One last question. If I export a local variable I can see it when running set | grep VR1 and also when executing env | grep VR1 . Does that mean that an env variable is a local variable at the same time ?

Comment: There's no distinction — variables are managed by the shell, and can be flagged (using [`export`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-export)) to be exported to the environment of new processes created by the shell. Running `export VR1` doesn't create a copy of `VR1`; it just flags that `VR1` must be exported.